# Inverse image functor commutes with finite limits

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, sheaf-theory

Let $\textbf{Sh}(X)$ be the category of sheaves of sets on a topological space $X$. A continuous map $f:X \to Y$ induces a pair of adjoint functors $f^{-1}:\textbf{Sh}(Y) \to \textbf{Sh}(X)$ and $f_*:\textbf{Sh}(X) \to \textbf{Sh}(Y)$. Why does $f^{-1}$ preserve finite limits?

I'm having trouble constructing the necessary unique maps from $\mathcal{E} \to f^{-1}\mathcal{L}$ for a finite limit $\mathcal{L} \in \textbf{Sh}(Y)$. Adjunction doesn't seem to help since my arrows are going in the wrong direction.

I can get an arrow $f^{-1}f_*\mathcal{E} \to f^{-1}\mathcal{L}$ by adjunction, but I only get a natural map $f^{-1}f_*\mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{E}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a really explicit description of $f^{-1}$ as
$$
f^{-1}{\cal G}:U\mapsto \underset{V\supseteq fU}{\text{colim }} {\cal G}V
$$
($\cal G$ a sheaf on $Y$, $U$ an open subset of $X$, $V$ open subsets of $Y$); this colimit is [filtered](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/filtered+category), and since (a) finite limits in ${\bf Sh}(A)$ are computed pointwise and (b) filtered colimits commute -in $\bf Set$- with finite limits, you have the result that $f^{-1}$ is left exact.

There are, I think, even more formal ways to prove this statement. Whether you want them or not depends on what grip you want on the result :-)

Comment: Thanks! At the moment, this is enough for me to chew on. Is it straight-forward to show (b)? I'm finding it hard to formulate the statement I need to prove in terms of functors.

Comment: It's like computing the form of Laplace operator in spherical coordinates, everybody did it, nobody wants to remember that they did. I bet there is a complete proof on the $n$Lab; I'm quite sure Kashiwara and Schapira "Categories and Sheaves" contains a proof; I'm also sure there is a proof of the statement in Borceux, or in Mac Lane's *Categories Work*. It's up to you to decide if you want to give it a try alone.

Comment: If you want a point where to start, there is a canonical map
$$
\text{colim}_J \text{lim}_I F \xrightarrow{\qquad} \text{lim}_I\text{colim}_J F
$$ the proof I know rudely shows that this is a bijection when $J$ is filtered and $I$ is finite. So I think there's no other way than defining it (it's a function of sets) and show it is injective and surjective. I'd be glad to see more elegant arguments though!

Comment: Awesome! I'll try it out and check out the references if I get stuck.

Comment: @FoscoLoregian Though I agree that the heart of the proof is that filtered colimits are exact in the category of sets, there is problem with your argument : $f^{-1}\mathcal{G}$ is *the sheaf associated with* the presheaf $U\mapsto\operatorname{colim}_{V\supset f(U)}\mathcal{G}(V)$. You also need that the sheafification functor is exact, or looking at stalks.

Comment: You're right, sure. (And then there's the bit of proof where you show that sheafification is left exact too.)